# TypeError: Video.Client is not a constructor (twilio)

Tags: javascript, twilio

I am tring on connect twilio video sdk and then try to connet it for video but geeting this error

> TypeError: Video.Client is not a constructor

```
    const Video = require('twilio-video');

..............
..............
     videoClient = new Video.Client($scope.videoToken);

         videoClient.connect({
              to: roomName
            }).then(roomJoined, function(error) {
              $scope.isError = true;
              $log.debug('Could not connect to Twilio: ' + error.message);
              $log.debug(error);
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks like the way to connect to Video has changed between beta4 and beta5. [Check out the Twilio Video beta5 docs here](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0-beta5/docs/).

You now want to connect like so:

```
const Video = require('twilio-video');

Video.connect($scope.videoToken, { name: roomName })
  .then(roomJoined)
  .catch(function(error) {
    $scope.isError = true;
    $log.debug('Could not connect to Twilio: ' + error.message);
    $log.debug(error);
  })
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: How can I disable audio in beta5 version? In beta4 this code worked: localMedia = new Video.LocalMedia(); localMedia.removeMicrophone();

Comment: First up, Video is released as v1 now, so I would change from beta5 to the v1 code. Then, to mute your local audio, you can do so in the context of a room like this: `var localMedia = room.localParticipant.media; localMedia.tracks.forEach(function (track) { track.disable(); })`. There's more detail here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/guide-preview/tracks#mute-one

Comment: Please, could you see this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44057718/remove-and-add-microphone-at-beta5-version